# How to display image from drop down using linked values with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, drop-down-menu

I just want to display the correct image upon selecting an option in the drop down. I am able to display the image if the option value is the same as the displaying value; however, I'm not sure how to display using the echo rather than the value. For example, if the option value is 1 and the filename is `image.jpeg`, the image source will be `uploads/1`, rather than `uploads/image.jpeg`.

```
<select class = "form-control" id="changeImage" onChange="changeImage" name="changeImage">
   <option disabled selected value> -- select an image -- </option> 
        <?php
           foreach($images as $imagedrop){
         ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $imagedrop['id'] ?>">
         <?php echo $imagedrop['filename'] ?> </option>
         <?php
            }
         ?>
</select>  
<script>           
  $('#changeImage').change(function(){
      $('#image')[0].src= 'uploads/'+this.value;
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to $().text()

```
$('#changeImage').change(function(){
  var image = $(this);
  var selectedIndex = image.prop('selectedIndex');
  var optionName = $('option', this).eq(selectedIndex).text();
  $('#image').prop('src', 'uploads/' + optionName);
});
```

Or..

```
$('#changeImage').change(function(){
  var image = $(this);
  var selectedValue = image.val();
  var optionName = $('option[value=' + selectedValue + ']').text();
  $('#image').prop('src', 'uploads/' + optionName);
});
```

---- EDIT

please edit your PHP code like below (no spaces)

```
<select class = "form-control" id="changeImage" onChange="changeImage" name="changeImage">
   <option disabled selected value> -- select an image -- </option> 
        <?php
           foreach($images as $imagedrop){
         ?><option value="<?php echo $imagedrop['id'] ?>"><?php echo $imagedrop['filename'] ?></option>
         <?php
            }
         ?>
</select>  
<script>           
  $('#changeImage').change(function(){
      $('#image')[0].src= 'uploads/'+this.value;
  });
</script>
```

OR.. use trim()

```
$('#changeImage').change(function(){
  var image = $(this);
  var selectedIndex = image.prop('selectedIndex');
  var optionName = $('option', this).eq(selectedIndex).text().trim(); // trim here!
  $('#image').prop('src', 'uploads/' + optionName);
});
```

Or.. (and)

```
$('#changeImage').change(function(){
  var image = $(this);
  var selectedValue = image.val();
  var optionName = $('option[value=' + selectedValue + ']').text().trim(); // trim here!
  $('#image').prop('src', 'uploads/' + optionName);
});
```

--- EDIT again.

```
<?php
  $options = array();
  foreach($images as $imagedrop) {
    $options[] = sprintf('<option value="%d">%s</option>', $imagedrop['id'], $imagedrop['filename']);
  }
?>
<select class = "form-control" id="changeImage" onChange="changeImage" name="changeImage">
   <option disabled selected value> -- select an image -- </option> 
   <?php echo implode('   \n' /* for bueaty html source, use '' */, $options); ?>
</select>  

<script>           
  $('#changeImage').change(function(){
    var image = $(this);
    var selectedIndex = image.prop('selectedIndex');
    var optionName = $('option', this).eq(selectedIndex).text().trim(); // trim here!
    $('#image').prop('src', 'uploads/' + optionName);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It's somewhat close, I'm receiving a lot of %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20 before the filename.

Comment: Use trim() for space(' ' - encoded for %20 ASCII code).

Comment: Thanks guys it worked, adding .trim() after optionName fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var pictureList = [
    "http://lorempixel.com/uploads/image.jpeg",
    "http://lorempixel.com/uploads/image.jpeg",
    "http://lorempixel.com/uploads/image.jpeg",
    "http://lorempixel.com/uploads/image.jpeg",
    "http://lorempixel.com/uploads/image.jpeg", ];

$('#changeImage').change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('#changeImage').val());
    $('image').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
});
```

The Picturelist var is basically an array. so if you say picturelist[1] you get the first link in the var.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the image i'm trying to call is from a database called image and I want the this.value to be something like this.echo

Comment: If every imagedrop is from a database it probably has a URL so if you give the value of the option element the url you can change it that way.

Comment: the option value has to be an int value which represents the primary key of the image table. I want to call the echo'd filename within the drop down to the img src url